# LocalForage and Angular-cli, step to import an external library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, localforage

What are the steps to include an external library such localForage in a Angular CLI project !?

LocalForage: https://github.com/localForage/localForage

Following the README.md file provided by LocalForage

1. Install the package: `npm install localforage`
2. Add the script into my angular.cli
   `"scripts": ["../node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.min.js"],`

   **3. Now I have to import localForage to be recognized by typescript
    
   `"import localForage from" localforage ";`** 
   But, how can I import the localForage into my tsconfig.json??

Answer (score 1):

You need do nothing to get typings files for library packages that include d.ts files. Angular packages include them already.

3. **Solution**: Just import localForage using:
   **`import * as localForage from "localforage";`**